# Inserting icon from fontawesome into html fails

Tags: html, css

Even though I gave the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
```

into the html file but when embedding the

```
<p class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass-minus"></i></p>
```

tag to insert the icon does not work, sometimes Some other icons like `"fa fa-envelope"` are fine. I don't understand why, please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. There is not enough information to be able to help or debug this issue. You need to include the code you are using and any errors encountered. You can use the developers console to check any errors - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there are multiple fontawesome version, paid for and free, so some fonts wont load.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see that icon isn't available for FA5 https://fontawesome.com/v5/search?q=magnifying.

But it is on FontAwesome 6 => https://fontawesome.com/icons/magnifying-glass-minus?f=classic&s=solid

Here I just changed the version of the FA asset loaded from a cdn:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass-minus">
```

Answer (score 1):

This icon is not exist in font-awesome 5 version.
Try to use font-awesome **6.4** version instead of 5.15.

If your site is large try to use an image for magnifying-glass-minus instead of icon. It'll help you. And will not disturbed remaining icons.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass-minus">
```